# Method overriding in python class multiple inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding, multiple-inheritance

I have a `Base` class that is inherited by two classes `Adder` and `subtractor` in which I have overridden the method called `test_func()` to adapt to respective class properties.

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, K):
        self.K = K
    def test_func(self):
        'Must be overridden since used by another_func()'
        return self.K
    def another_func(self):
        return self.K * self.test_func()

class Adder(Base):
    def __init__(self, K, M):
        Base.__init__(self, K)
        self.M = M
    def test_func(self):
        return self.M + self.K

class Subtractor(Base):
    def __init__(self, K, N):
        Base.__init__(self, K)
        self.N = N
    def test_func(self):
        return self.N - self.K
```

I am writing a superclass called `Algebra` that inherits both `Adder` and `Subtractor`.

```
class Algebra(Adder, Subtractor):
    def __init__(self, K, M, N):
        Adder.__init__(self, K, M)
        Subtractor.__init__(self, K, N)
```

Now I want to use the `test_func()` method selectively from `Adder` or `Subtractor` in the superclass `Algebra`. Is there a way in which I can do this? I tried

```
G = Algebra(K=2, M=5, N=7)
G.test_func()
>> 7
```

but it only takes method from `Adder` class. Is ther a way I can tell the superclass which class to evaluate the method from? For example,

```
G.test_func('Adder')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get this result would be to redefine `Algebra.test_func()` to make it explicitly work that way, ie:

```
class Algebra(Adder, Subtractor):
    def __init__(self, K, M, N):
        Adder.__init__(self, K, M)
        Subtractor.__init__(self, K, N)

    def test_func(self, which):
        if which == "Adder"):
            return Adder.test_func(self)
        elif which == "Subtractor":
            return Subtractor.test_func(self)
        else:
            raise ValueError("don't know %s" % which)
```

BUT this is a complete mess and a perfect example of inheritance abuse. Inheritance implies a "is a" relationship, and this means that any subclass of `Base` should keep a compatible interface (the same client code must be able to work the same with instances of whatever `Base` subclass)  - which the above doesn't.

Now ask yourself: is an `Algebra` an `Adder` and a `Subtractor` ? If yes, then your design issue is with `test_func()` itself. Else (an `Algebra` has an `Adder` and a `Subtractor`), do not inherit from `Adder` and `Subtractor` but use composition/delegation instead.

Comment: Thanks for the trick. Yes, it seems I am abusing inheritance for my particular problem. I my code, the `Base` class is a solver that takes `test_funct()` as particular function that is specific to the child class. The solver then uses this function to compute other functions. Therefore it was not possible for me to just have separate definitions of `test_func` but had to override it in child class.
This is a good trick to get me going; but I'll refactor my code and see if I can avoid using this weird construction.

Answer (score 2):

Don't override `test_func`; provide *two* methods, each of which calls the desired parent class's `test_func`.

```
class Algebra(Adder, Subtractor):
    def __init__(self, K, M, N):
        Adder.__init__(self, K, M)
        Subtractor.__init__(self, K, N)

    def test_adder_func(self):
        return Adder.test_func(self)

    def test_subtractor_func(self):
        return Subtractor.test_func(self)
```

I am ignoring any deeper question, like why you chose multiple inheritance here.

Comment: Thanks for raising the deeper issue! I need to override the function since it is used by other methods in the `Base` class. I've updated this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The way inheritance works is

1. Most of the time you will have reference wiht parent class
2. Instantiation with child class

In your case, instead of

```py
G = Algebra(K=2, M=5, N=7)
```

You should say

```py
G = Adder(K=2, M=5, N=7)
```

And then call the respective function by `G.test_func()`

In your example, the runtime would never know how to call the child method because you have instantiated a parent object.